# How to Configure SSMA to convert DB2 INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, sql-server-migration-assi

I am trying to use the Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for DB2 v7.5 to migrate from DB2 v 11.1 to SQL Server 2014. The DB2 columns defined as `INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` are getting converted to an `Integer` but not `IDENTITY` on the SQL Server side. How can I get SSMA to convert the DB2 `IDENTITY` columns to SQL Server `Identity` columns?

Source DB2:

```
"RECID" INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 NO CYCLE CACHE 20 NO ORDER),
```

Generated SQL for SQL Server:

```
[RECID] int  NOT NULL,
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, should be Configure SSMA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually update the generated schema for the SQL server to add the Identity attribute.  Once I did that, everything appeared to work correctly.